# Query Efficiency - relational data lookups for comments, likes, etc

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, web-services, database-design, relational-database

Relational Database with these tables:

- Users

  - user_id
  - image_url
- Products

  - product_id
- Comments

  - product_id
  - user_id

To pull comments for a product is just a join, but to also include the user's image_url I must do a lookup for each comment to find it's associated user data.

I can think of a few ways to handle this:

- Separate comment DB to offset load with added lookups and general caching solutions
- Create redundant data on the comment table that may be out of date

I'm just assuming that there is a better way of dealing with this problem to make it super clean. Can anyone suggest a better alternative?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you specify your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

I am just curious: why can't it be a three way join? You are joining Products with Comments on product_id. Why not join it with Users as well on user_id (which is in Comments)? Since it is too simple and obvious, I must be missing something but still I wanted to throw it out there :-)

Comment: No no, I appreciate the candid response. I think i left out a critical piece of this. I'm specifically trying to increase the efficiency of the join, or avoid a join altogether. In other words, to make this a < 300ms instead of 1000ms+ for larger joins.